# вызов метода, пока переменная не сменила значение, и обрыв, если сменила

Tags: swift

например есть у меня переменная `X = 0`, 
я должен вызывать метод `getStatus()` который отправляет запрос на сервер и обновляет переменную `Y`, и пока `X == Y` я повторно отправляю запрос на сервер каждые 2 сек на протяжении 10 сек, если например во время какого-то их запросов, пришел `Y = 1`, то есть `Y != X` - я обрываю цикл и перестаю слать запросы, если по истечению 10 сек они все еще равны, покажу алерт.

пробовал сделать так, но способ не подходящий, так как цикл отрабатываются моментально, а методы в памяти вызываются по таймеру, но помнят старый, не обновленный одним из запросов `Y`:

```
func valueInspection() {
    var time = 2
    for _ in 1...10 {
        if x == y {
            time += 2
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(time), target: self, selector: #selector(General.getStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        } else {
          print ("VALUE CHANCHED")
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: в `getStatus()` если не совпадают, останавливать таймер?

Comment: @VAndrJ 
в `getStatus()` при получении данных, меняется значение проперти `Y` .
По нажатию на кнопку я отправляю запрос на сервер по смене переменной `Y`, назовем `valueChange()`, и в нем вызывается метод по проверке состояния `valueInspection()`, поменялось или нет, о котором собственно вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func valueInspection() {

    if timer == nil {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(vc.getStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
}


func getStatus() {

...

if timer != nil {
    counterTimer += 1

    if x != y {
                        timer.invalidate()
                        timer = nil
                        counterTimer = 0
                    } else {
                        if counterTimer == 5 {
                            timer.invalidate()
                            timer = nil
                            counterTimer = 0
                             present(UIAlertController.addAllert("Oops..", message: "Try Again"), animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x: Int = 1
var y: Int = 1
var startTimestamp: TimeInterval = 0
private let timeout: TimeInterval = 10

func valueInspection() {
    startTimestamp = NSTimeIntervalSince1970

    delayedInspection(delay: 0)
}

private func delayedInspection(delay: UInt64) {
    guard startTimestamp > NSTimeIntervalSince1970 - timeout * 1000 else { return }

    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeout) {
        if x == y {
            delayedInspection(delay: 2)
            // send request
        } else {
            print("value changed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не заходит в  let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime, execute: {
            if self.currentguard == self.guardCar {
                self.delayedInspection(delay: 2)
                // send request
            } else {
                print("value changed")
            }
        })
`

Comment: не заходит в 
` let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime, execute: {
            if self.currentguard == self.guardCar {
                self.delayedInspection(delay: 2)
                // send request
            } else {
                print("value changed")
            }
        })
`

Comment: @pbogdanv Исправил, проверил в playground, все вроде бы ок

Answer (score 0):

почему бы тебе не использовать цикл

`repeat {
    statements
} while condition`

например

```
var time = 2
repeat {
    time += 2
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(time), target: self, selector: #selector(General.getStatus), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    if time == 10 {
       break
    }
} while x != y
```

Comment: дело в том, что конструкции циклов отрабатываются моментально, то есть все запросы по таймеру выставляться сразу в очередь, в зависимости от текущего Y, а нужно не от текущего на начале цикла, а от полученного: отправился первый запрос -> если Y=0 через 2 сек отправили повторно, если Y=0, то повторить, если Y=1 остановить процесс, ну и если прошло 10 сек и все без изменений (Y=0) то тоже остановить с сообщением